# Regex to match 2 different parts of a line

Tags: regex, string, lua

I'm working in lua, and i need to match 2 parts of a line that's taken in through file IO. I'm inexperienced with regexes and i'm told lua doesn't have full regex support built in (but i have a library that provides that if need be). Can someone help me with building regexes to match the parts necessary?

```
    "bor_adaptor_00.odf" 3.778
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^
         i need this in      and this in
         a string            a number
```

Comment: Just looks like you're splitting based on two or more whitespace characters, right?  I don't want to pollute the answers because I'm not familiar with Lua, but this seems like an approach you can take.

Comment: you can check the string library in Lua documentation in the installation folder, ie file:///.../Lua/5.1/docs/luarefv51.html#The_string_library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^"(.*?)"\s+(\d[\d.]*)$
```

Explanation:

- ^ = line start
- "(.*?)" = save everything between " and " to a capture group
- \s+ = any number >= 1 of whitespace chars
- (\d[\d.]*) = a digit followed by more digits or dots
- $ = end of line

No idea how to use that in lua, but should help to get you started.

On the other hand, this is a really simple string, so it could be a good idea to parse it without regular expressions.

Comment: You're right, i think i can use lua's tools to simply parse it down to a number and a word, and go from there

Answer (score 3):

I made an example:

```
s = '"bor_adaptor_00.odf" 3.778'
val1, val2 = string.match(s,'(%b"")%s*([.0-9]*)')
print(val1, val2)
```

output:

```
"bor_adaptor_00.odf"    3.778
```